# UIStackView subclass with static spacing

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, subclass

I am creating a subclass of UIStackView, and I want spacing to be static and non-overwritable. I thought this would be simply done by overriding the `spacing` property:

```
class MyStackView: UIStackView {
    override var spacing: CGFloat {
        get { return 8.0 }
        set {}
    }
}
```

This, however, does not work. The getter is never called and no spacing is displayed. The only solution I found for this is the following piece of code:

```
class MyStackView: UIStackView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        super.spacing = 8.0
    }

    override var spacing: CGFloat {
        get { return 8.0 }
        set {}
    }
}
```

It actually doesn't matter what I return in `get`, it's never called by anything anyway.

Can anybody explain this behavious]r and how to avoid it?

Comment: Can you try overriding the `set`? Apart from the `init`, if subclasses, call `set`, your override will prevent them from overriding, right?

Comment: True, but in this case it is a custom UI component that is not designed to be overwritten. So I simply want spacing to always be `8.0`, no matter what.

Comment: So, if your override, `set`, shouldn't that do the trick? Because if some one tries to set a different value, overriding set will not let that take effect.

Comment: but I did overwrite set in the above code (using `set {}`).

Comment: Maybe... for your first attempt, use `set { super.spacing = 8.0 }` ?

Comment: yeah this is what I‘m doing now. Still would be interested in what is happening here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion here what's happening. You want to achieve two things:

1. Spacing at `MyStackView` should be `8.0` by default
2. That spacing value should not be changeable from outside

To achieve the first thing you need to override the initializers and set your default value inside on them.

```
class MyStackView: UIStackView {

    private let defaultSpacing: CGFloat = 8.0

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        super.spacing = defaultSpacing
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        super.spacing = defaultSpacing
    }

}
```

For the second thing, you need to override the `getter` and `setter` of `spacing` to get the control on any changing from the outside.

```
class MyStackView: UIStackView {

    ...

    override var spacing: CGFloat {
        get { return defaultSpacing }
        set { print("MyStackView spacing it always \(defaultSpacing)") }
    }

}
```

**Why can't you simply override a variable and get the same result?**

`UIStackView.spacing` property is computed, it's not a container. We might not care how does original `getter` works because we know that our spacing is always the same. We know its value and can always return it at overriden getter.

But we also don't know how does original `setter` works and what changes  does it make in `UIStackView`. Since that, we can't simply override `getter`. We have to explicitly call `super.spacing = defaultValue` once, to trigger original `setter` and set the desired value.

Comment: thanks for the explanation and the approach seems sensible